# TypeScript: Use Enum as filter for Interface/Object keys in Compile Time

Tags: typescript, filter, enums, interface, intersection

## Question

I have an `enum` (string to string) that contains valid keys for a `function`.  I also have an `object` (or `interface`) that has some keys in the enum, and some not.

How can I set the parameter of my function to only be **only the keys from the `interface` that exist in the `enum`**? (e.g. Pick, Extract, Intersection, whatever you wanna call them, that properly preserves the keys.)

## Example

The following example is irrelevant to my project, but proper exhibits my need.

Let's say the `enum` and the `interface` are as following:

```
enum PromotableProperties {
  SALARY = "salary",
  SIGNON_BONUS = "signonBonus",
  ANNUAL_BONUS = "annualBonus",
}

interface IExistingEmployee {
  id:           number;
  name:         string;
  salary:       number;
  signonBonus:  number;
  age:          number;
}
```

Now the actual code is:

```
type ValidPropsOf<ENUM_T, OBJ_T> = ...; // I want this!

type PromotablePropsForExistingEmployee = ValidPropsOf<PromotableProperties, IExistingEmployee>;


function promoteEmployeeBy(
  emp: IExistingEmployee,
  prop: ValidPropsOf<PromotableProperties, IExistingEmployee>,
  byValue: number,
): void {
  emp[prop] += byValue;
  console.log(`${emp.name}'s ${prop} is increase by ${byValue}'`);
}

const goodOldJohn: IExistingEmployee = {
  id: 5,
  name: "john",
  salary: 20000,
  signonBonus: 1000,
  age: 25,
};

promoteEmployeeBy(goodOldJohn, PromotableProperties.SALARY, 100);
promoteEmployeeBy(goodOldJohn, PromotableProperties.ANNUAL_BONUS, 100); // Error
promoteEmployeeBy(goodOldJohn, "age", 100); // Error
```

Note that the second function call should fail, because `ANNUAL_BONUS` doesn't exist in the `IExistingEmployee`, and the third call should fail because `age` is not in `PromotableProperties`.

### What I need

... is the utility type of `type ValidPropsOf<ENUM_T, OBJ_T> = ...` the returns the keys that exist in both the enum (as value) and the object/interface.

### TS Playground

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewggLgQwEYBtjwQB2DhQEtgBnKAbwCgooBlAQQBkmAlATSgF4oAicmixo4AT34AaOowCSAcQByAeUUB9AEKqAqg14DyJAOYgEIDWbDkpMposXbWmnXr780IcMIvhr0gL40NCQgKEQAZmgAxsBQsgCiAB4k5KQgRvEQ%20FgIYsCxtPQkACYAXPQVlfTgEBhEANwyIGgQwOVVFalwIUaN9EIi4u1VNXVwfVCGJmY%20Vu2jDTJoRm0dlQvjNIE0KGKEUABqwiV4%20OTK4QA88Q4AsmoAKpJQyhoAUo8AfPoAdH%20Nu32eGQ6GwuEQZwAYgg4EkUmkMlkcnlYnwjlgThDzldgahMDhTkRSBRnglkqkeplsrl8p9GjRwmAQFFSGYoPhECDgFTkfkNGIABQyYBZcpk%20GUpE04DSegcgjlXGgglY6Gw8kInnS2VQDBidFgVYbaQASnKADcECVqMKsgBteX4AC6UAA1Hw9QbgBMomZyAgcD8ckYBQADAAkVBF%20B%20zVa-gA5JRI47-FAUunmXBgGhyLE9VBI57hIbE6GTY1tr6QKkoEYEAhisosMU3ggABYgMVwinpLUo-SFdNlKAAVh1cdW-AAVh2QDZ%20sJRGJygAmAAMm-XOqmpnMlnI5QAjFudctVqvx1t6fKuf2%20YL643m62588lfjwQQiWRyD9mGwXDPCe64VjQt6oNyUoovyApPk2LZtp276cniYKEsQv4-HYDhOFoDgMMBm4VlAAD0pFQPEcCIHA4GoWE97ALB8EvkhIDPO4KxSFAIEkeRlHUTCQQ0EAA).

Answer (score 0):

### What didn't work

I assumed `Extract` (from the [TS official Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)) should work, but I couldn't get it to work.

I also tried `Pick` and a bunch of other utility types from the two known TS Utility repos, I knew of, but none helped.

1. https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types
2. https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials

### What did work

What did work for me was a double `Exclude`!  It was:

```
type ValidPropsOf<ENUM_T, OBJ_T> = Exclude<ENUM_T, Exclude<ENUM_T, keyof OBJ_T>>;
```

Apparently `Exclude` preserves the keys properly (and doesn't aggressively generalize individual keys).  So From the `enum` I take out the ones that don't exist in the `object` (call them `badProps`), and the the good ones would be `goodProps = allProps - badProps`.

It completely preserved the individual keys.  You can test it by hovering over the type in the function in this [working TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=36&pln=15&pc=81#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewggLgQwEYBtjwQB2DhQEtgBnKAbwCgooBlAQQBkmAlATSgF4oAicmixo4AT34AaOowCSAcQByAeUUB9AEKqAqg14DyJAOYgEIDWbDkpMposXbWmnXr780IcMIvhr0gL40NCQgKEQAZmgAxsBQsgCiAB4k5KQgRvEQ%20FgIYsCxtPQkACYAXPQVlfTgEBhEANwyIGgQwOVVFalwIUaN9EIi4u1VNXVwfVCGJmY%20Vu2jDTJoRm0dlQvjNIE0KGKEUABqwiV4%20OTK4QA88Q4AsmoAKpJQyhoAUo8AfPpJUVhgxWA1zuj2ev3%20gOB2nuTygAGtgGIEOEXu8vp9Grt9nhkOhsLhEGcAGIIOBJFJpDJZHJ5WJ8I5YE6E85XHGoTA4U5EUgUZ4JZKpHqZbK5fIYoLhMAgKKkMxQfCIXHAYU0-IaMQAChkwCy5X5FKF1NFwGk9AVBHKbLxnOZJLJAspKuNpqgGDEDLAqw20gAlOUAG4IErUbVZADa5vwAF0oABqPhuj3ACZRMzkBA4AB0OSMGoABgASKg6-CZ5qtfwAckoRcj-igKQb0rgwDQ5FibqgRcTwk9VbzPsa21TIFSUCMCAQxWUWGKbwQAAsQHryYL0k7afpCg2ylAAKwu8urfgAK0XIBs-WEojE5QATAAGJ8Pl1TUzmSzkcoARmfLuWqx3geWyNDQ5pKhuaqahOU4znO57PFaHIEgQ3JkOQmbMGwXDPL%20D6DmBiqoMqRq0uqGowdOs7zkuiFEdaKGEMQ6GZnYDhOFoDgMLhT6DlAAD0-FQPEcCIHAhFIMRkHAORlFwTRIDPO4KxSFAeF8YJwmiaSQQ0EAA).